# Passing a value to a delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I'm trying to pass a value to a method in the delegate and return an `NSString` value. For some reason, i get a property not found on delegate error. I'd appreciate any help. Here is my code:

**delegate.h**

```
- (NSString*) getSoundFilePath:(int)pageNumber;
```

**delegate.m**

```
-(NSString*) getSoundFilePath:(int)pageNumber{
    switch (pageNumber) {
        case 1:
            return soundFilePathPage1;
            break;
        case 2:
            return soundFilePathPage2;
            break;
        case 3:
            return soundFilePathPage3;
            break;
        case 4:
            return soundFilePathPage4;
            break;
        case 5:
            return soundFilePathPage5;
            break;
        case 6:
            return soundFilePathPage6;
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**app.m**

```
int page = 1;
NSString *audioFilePath = appDelegate.getSoundFilePath:page; 
//that's where i get the error
```

Comment: It's a perfectly fine error. Your app delegate does not have a property named `getSoundFilePath`, it has a *method* named `getSoundFilePath:`. And even if it had, you can’t pass parameters to properties. As stated in the answer, you should really read some introduction to objective-C.

Comment: Note also that a leading "get" in a method name has a specific meaning in ObjC (it means the method takes a pointer that will be updated with the return value). The correct name for this method is `soundFilePathForPageNumber:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look for an objective c introduction.

The correct line would be

```
NSString *audioFilePath = [appDelegate getSoundFilePath:page];
```

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for that. Am i right in saying the syntax i was using was "setter" syntax while the square brackets are essentially "getter" syntax?

Comment: no, getter and setter are both accessed through brackets, since they are methods. by class.property, you access the property directly without using a setter or getter. Since you declared a method, you can't access it as a property.

Comment: @jimpic Actually, by `class.property` you are still using the setter/getter. It's just a shorter way to write the method call. And in general, getter methods can be used with dot syntax even if they are not declared as properties.

Comment: @Sulthan's point is very important. `object.property` is *just* another way to write `[object property]`. It does *not* mean "read a property." It does not mean "read an ivar." It means "pass a message and return the result." There is no rule whatsoever that the requested method actually return the value of an ivar. It is bad style, however, to use dot-notation on anything that would have a side-effect (even though it's legal).